# Herkunft von "roter Faden"

Tags: etymology

> Unter einem „roten Faden“ versteht man eine Spur, einen Weg oder auch
> eine Richtlinie. Etwas zieht sich wie ein roter Faden durch etwas. ([Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/roter_Faden)).

Mir wurde heute sehr überzeugend erklärt, dass der Begriff "rote Faden" aus der griechischen Mythologie stammt und zwar vom [Ariadnefaden](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariadnefaden). Dank des (roten?) Fadens von Prinzessin Ariadne fand Theseus den Weg durch das Labyrinth des Minotauros. Im dazugehörigen Wikipedia steht dazu nichts, allerdings ist unter "siehe auch" der Arikel über den rote Faden verlinkt.

In [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/roter_Faden) steht zur Herkunft von "roter Faden":

> Übernommen aus den „Wahlverwandtschaften“ von Johann Wolfgang von Goethe:
>
> „Wir hören von einer besondern Einrichtung bei der englischen Marine. Sämtliche Tauwerke der königlichen Flotte, vom stärksten bis
> zum schwächsten, sind dergestalt gesponnen, dass ein roter Faden durch
> das Ganze durchgeht, den man nicht herauswinden kann, ohne alles
> aufzulösen, und woran auch die kleinsten Stücke kenntlich sind, dass
> sie der Krone gehören.“ (Teil 2, Kapitel 2)
>
> „Ebenso zieht sich durch Ottiliens Tagebuch ein Faden der Neigung und Anhänglichkeit, der alles verbindet und das Ganze bezeichnet.“
> (Teil 2, Kapitel 4)
>
> Der durchgehende rote Faden im Tauwerk wird hier verglichen mit dem immer wiederkehrenden Motiv in Ottilies Tagebuch.

Und im [Wikipediaartikel zu Faden](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faden#Roter_Faden) steht zudem noch:

> Schon im ersten Buch der Bibel begegnet allerdings der „rote Faden“
> als Unterscheidungsmerkmal zwischen Zwillingsbrüdern: „Bei der Geburt
> streckte einer die Hand heraus. Die Hebamme griff zu, band einen roten
> Faden um die Hand und sagte: Er ist zuerst herausgekommen.“ (Gen 38,28
> EU)

**Was ist denn nun die Herkunft des Wortes? Ist es sicher der rote Faden der englischen Marine oder etwa doch der Ariadnefaden?**

Comment: Ich erinnere mich dunkel an einen Märchenfilm, in dem ein roter Faden in einem Labyrinth liegt und abbrennt. Der Film ist offensichtlich relativ jung, verglichen mit Goethe, aber falls ein altes Märchen zugrunde liegt ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Der Ariadnefaden wird zwar oft als Quelle genannt, aber in keiner mir vorliegenden Fassung einer mythologischen Beschreibung wird irgend eine Farbe dieses Fadens erwähnt. Weder rot noch eine andere Farbe. Daher halte ich den Ariadnefaden nicht für den Ursprung des roten Fadens. Außerdem liest man daraus nur bedingt die Bedeutung »wiederkehrendes Motiv« heraus.

Den in der Bibel erwähnten roten Faden um das Handgelenk eines Fötus kennt man auch schon sehr lange, aber er hat nicht die Bedeutung des Sprichwortes, und korreliert auch viel weniger gut mit dem zeitlichen Auftreten des Begriffs im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch, daher würde ich auch diesen Ursprung ausschließen.

Der rote Faden aus Goethes Wahlverwandtschaften wird hingegen genau in dem heutigen sprichwörtlichen Sinn verwendet. Ein [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=roter+Faden%2C+roten+Faden&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Croter%20Faden%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Croten%20Faden%3B%2Cc0) verrät auch, dass der Begriff erst seit ca. 1860 Teil des deutschen Wortschatzes ist, was 50 Jahre nach Erscheinen von Goethes Roman ist. Insofern liegt es nahe, in Goethes Buch den Ursprung des sprichwörtlichen Begriffs zu sehen.

Der im erwähnten Buch beschriebene Kennfaden der britischen Marine war zwar der Auslöser für Goethes Vergleich mit einem ständig wiederkehrenden Motiv, aber davon ist der sprichwörtliche rote Faden nur indirekt (eben über Goethes Roman) abgeleitet. Ich habe zwar keine Belege dafür gefunden, vermute aber, dass die britische Marine schon sehr viel länger einen roten Kennfaden in ihre Produkte einwebt. Wäre dieser Faden der direkte Ursprung des Sprichwortes, würde man es eher im Englischen kennen als im Deutschen. Im Englischen ist eine vergleichbare Redewendung aber unbekannt.

Comment: Aber auf Französisch! Laut Ngram ist "fil rouge" explosionsartig 1722 als Begriff entstanden, also lange vor Goethe. Eine Etymologie des französischen Begriffes konnte ich aber auch nicht finden.

Comment: Ob allerdings die Bedeutung von *fil rouge* in der französischen Literatur des 18. Jahrhunderts gleich unserem "roten Faden" ist, sei dahingestellt. Ein Blick in die Google Books ergibt, dass es sich vermutlich nur um irgendwelche rote Bändel, Schleifen, Bänder o.ä. handelt. Die Franzosen schwanken bei der Etymologie ihres *fil rouge* selbst zwischen Ariadnefaden und Goethe.

Comment: @DelioMugnolo: Dein »explosionsartiges« Auftreten, das du im Ngram sehen willst, ist ein kurzes Aufflackern, das noch dazu von geringer Signifikanz begleitet ist. Stelle mal die Glättung auf 0, dann siehst du, dass im fraglichen Zeitraum der Begriff »fil rouge« nur 1725 (mit einer Häufigkeit von 0,0000547184%), 1728 (mit 0,0001220541%), 1733 (0,0000120595%) und danach auch noch ein paar mal sporadisch auftaucht.

Comment: (Fortsetzung) Wenn der Korpus eines Jahres nur rund ca. 8 Millionen Wörter umfasst, dann heißt das, dass 1725 der Begriff in der gesamten zur verfügung stehenden Literatur 4-mal verwendet wurde, 1728 10-mal (möglicherweise in einem Handarbeitsbuch) und 1733 überhaupt nur einmal. »Explosionsartig« geht anders.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Vielleicht hast Du Recht. Jedenfalls scheint der Graph zu "fil rouge" kaum von der Veröffentlichung von Die Wahlverwandtschaften beeinflusst zu sein. Andererseits hast Du Recht, auch die Zitate vom Ende des 18. Jahrhunderts scheinen den Begriff mit einer anderen Bedeutung zu verwenden.

Comment: Das Englische kennt den Begriff *red thread* bzw. *red string* sehr wohl, allerdings nicht in unserer übertragenen Bedeutung, sondern als Ariadnefaden.

Comment: Achso: Das Schwedische kennt den Roten Faden auch und das Russische anscheinend auch. Und Sherlock Holmes sagte mal "'There’s the scarlet thread of murder running through the colourless skein of life...' "

Comment: Witzigerweise sind übrigens im Japanischen [verwandte Seelen](http://www.faena.com/aleph/articles/the-legend-of-the-red-string-of-japan/) durch einen roten Faden verbunden.

Answer (score 2):

Die Bibel kennt noch eine weitere Stelle, in der eine rote Schnur vor kommt; als Erkennungszeichen.
Jos 2,18 Siehe, wenn wir in das Land kommen, musst du diese rote Schnur in das Fenster binden, durch das du uns heruntergelassen hast, und musst deinen Vater, deine Mutter, deine Brüder und das ganze Haus deines Vaters zu dir ins Haus versammeln.
Jos 2,21 Da sagte sie: Wie ihr sagt, so sei es! Und sie entließ sie, und sie gingen weg. Sie aber band die rote Schnur ins Fenster.